# Prevent GRASS from converting utf-8 to latin-1

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, attribute-table, text

I am opening two shapefiles in `QGIS 2.18` and then perform a `v.overlay` from the `GRASS` toolbox. 
The shapefile contains attributes with characters that need `Utf-8` to display all the characters correctly. However, when I use `v.overlay`, the algorithm tries to convert all the characters to `latin-1` which does not work. A lot of characters are converted to `?`.

How do I tell `GRASS`, when used from `QGIS`, to use `utf-8`?

Comment: If anyone has an idea where in the QGIS project I can suggest a change in this, please let me know.

Comment: Please check here: http://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/bugreporting.html

Comment: @markusN Thanks. Wasnt sure wether its a bug or not. Could have been a feature ;)